# expandable css box

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

How to create a floating box which can be expanded using an expand handle on the right bottom corner. The expanding should occur both vertical and horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at the jQuery UI [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), it does exactly what you want it to do.

**Edit**

In fact looking over your question again the jQuery UI [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) may even be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resize property

```
    div.resize { width: 100px; 
                 height: 100px; 
                 border: 1px solid; 
                 resize: both; 
                 overflow: auto; 
               }
```